# show log of all the revisions prior to branch creation point when creating a branch

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have created a branch from Trunk at a particular revision. When I do a 'show log' on a particular file, I would like to see all the revisions associated with that file.However I can see only one revision that is related to branch creation assuming that no commits have been done after branch creation. Is it possible ? How?

Comment: Is the Stop on Copy checkbox checked in the Log dialog?

Comment: @alroc Exactly what I was looking for !! Unchecked and got the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the Stop on Copy/Rename checkbox in TortoiseSVN's Log dialog is checked. Unchecking it will trace the log history back past the point of branching (copying) to where the versioned item originated.

See also https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-showlog.html